# help installing Ruby 1.9.2 on Lion GM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm

Trying to setup Ruby on Rails in my Lion GM dev environment and having some trouble. Installed rvm, and when i try installing ruby i always get an error using rvm install 1.9.2 on my i5 iMAc. It gets to

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 - #compiling
```

and halts with the following error message:

```
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
update_terminal_cwd; 

in the log i get the following. Im also using Xcode 4.2 for lion. Thanks.


[2011-07-04 12:26:20] make 
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -L.  -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend   main.o dmydln.o dmyencoding.o dmyversion.o miniprelude.o array.o bignum.o class.o compar.o complex.o dir.o dln_find.o enum.o enumerator.o error.o eval.o load.o proc.o file.o gc.o hash.o inits.o io.o marshal.o math.o node.o numeric.o object.o pack.o parse.o process.o random.o range.o rational.o re.o regcomp.o regenc.o regerror.o regexec.o regparse.o regsyntax.o ruby.o safe.o signal.o sprintf.o st.o strftime.o string.o struct.o time.o transcode.o util.o variable.o compile.o debug.o iseq.o vm.o vm_dump.o thread.o cont.o ascii.o us_ascii.o unicode.o utf_8.o newline.o  dmyext.o -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  -o miniruby
<internal:prelude>: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0003 p:0000 s:0006 b:0006 l:000005 d:000005 TOP   
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001a68 d:001a68 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
<internal:prelude>:0:in `<compiled>'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: You should jump on the #rvm irc channel.  It's probably a bug in rvm, since Lion is new.

Comment: forgot to mention this is on a i5 imac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac OS X Lion is not yet released. I've read reports of several bugs in Lion GM (among which even as severe as kernel panics), this is probably also a Lion (or Xcode 4.2) bug, and if not, it's a Ruby bug. RVM is certainly not the cause, as your output indicates the compiled Ruby is crashing.

I would recommend that you wait until Lion is released.

Edit: Now that Lion and Xcode 4.1 is released, I see the issue has been fixed.

Comment: There is a way! See my answer, or just add `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` to your shell rc file. Lion sets the default compiler to LLVM, but you can change it back to gcc.

Answer (score 7):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170813/why-cant-i-install-rails-on-lion-using-rvm/6176991#6176991), and @Lehi Sanchez is mostly right; Apple is leaving gcc for llvm, but that doesn't mean gcc isn't included in Lion (provided you have the Xcode/Developer Tools package installed). It's at `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`. Just include the following in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever:

```
 export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Or, I suppose you could fire that line at your shell before you build your 1.9.2 with `rvm`. In either case, make sure that line is active and then fire your `rvm install 1.9.2` and presto!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. I checked the logs and found the following:

```
[2011-07-05 20:30:29]  ./configure --prefix=/Users/lsanchez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc  
checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin11.0.0
checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin11.0.0
checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin11.0.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/lsanchez/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

It turns out that Apple is leaving gcc behind for llvm. It looks like they don't even include it in Lion.

Comment: Im running my Ruby environment in a VM until things settle. Thats what I get for living on the bleeding edge.

Comment: No, that means you didn't install Xcode. If you `which gcc`, it should tell you `/usr/bin/gcc`