# How do I get "gem install" to work on OS X Lion with Ruby 1.8.7 without seg faulting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-lion

I am novice rails/terminal user and just did a fresh Lion install + Xcode after that.

Installed RVM but when I execute "gem install [any gem]" in terminal, I get this error:

```
/Users/[my user]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11.0.0]
Abort trap: 6
```

Can anyone help, please?

PS. I am using - and in the project I am working on, I must use ruby v1.8.7.

Comment: Thank you, this thread saved my life!!! ... .... ... Well, saved my day at least.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure your rvm is up to date: `rvm get latest`

And then run this: `rvm uninstall 1.8.7 && CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.8.7`

Basically you must tell rvm which gcc compiler to use (`CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`)

Then you should be able to install the pg gem as normal.

Comment: Thanks very much, Andrew. Unfortunately, after following your instructions, I still get exactly the same error message. Any other ideas to try out?   PS. Before trying your solution I executed this in terminal "export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2" (from the solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170813/why-cant-i-install-rails-on-lion-using-rvm). Maybe that messed something up so your solution doesn't work?

Comment: This fixed it for me. @rassom, make sure that you're doing the uninstall phase as well. Ruby has to be recompiled for 'gem install' to work on Lion + 1.8.7

Comment: If you're on a fresh install of Lion+Xcode, you will not have /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 available.  Install https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer for a copy of gcc (recommended by `rvm requirements`)

Comment: For me, 'uninstall' was insufficient; I had to use Polo's 'remove' command instead.

Comment: The reason that `rvm uninstall` can sometimes be insufficient is that that `rvm install` reuses the build directory without running `make clean`. You can either find the build directory and run it yourself, or `rvm remove` will completely delete it and download the tarball from scratch.

Answer (score 9):

uninstall it with

```
rvm remove 1.8.7
```

then do the

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.8.7
```

Comment: Thanks, Polo - that solved it. Accepted Andrews answer as it was mostly my novice status not seeing that it was two seperate commands, but wish I could accept both of your answers. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 4):

In Mac OSX Lion (10.7), gcc-4.2 is not installed.

So you must download the installer (https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) and install it, then run

```
rvm uninstall 1.8.7 && CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.8.7
```