# OSX Lion: export CC for rvm and homebrew enough? What about CXX, CPP, CXXPP

Tags: ruby, gcc, rvm, osx-lion

As I had major troubles installing ruby 1.8.7 on OSX Lion I did like it was proposed i.e. in one answer to [Why can't I install Rails on Lion using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170813/why-cant-i-install-rails-on-lion-using-rvm) and set my CC environment variable. I also used https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer to get the non-LLVM gcc.
I read that there could be problems with brews also, and gcc_select doesn't seem to be available anymore, so I decided to put this into my .zshrc:

```
# Lion ships with llvm-gcc-4.2 as default compiler, fix that as it breaks rubies and brews
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2
```

Now I'm wondering if there are other variables I should set, like CPP, CXXPP, LD, you name it. I'm not a gcc expert so could anyone lighten me up? What's the best practice here? I don't want to compile everything again so I figured I better ask :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be nothing else to set. If you install ox-gcc-installer alone, it will handle installing any and all ruby and gem setups. Ruby uses C, and thus, gems that are natively compiled are also C based. Setting CPP and CXX are basically the same thing as CXX is for the C++ compiler binary, as well as CPP.

The only issue you should have with osx-gcc-installer and what you can do with RVM is that Node.js relies on Carbon headers which are only in the Xcode installer package, not osx-gcc-installer as its a strip job. That can easily be fixed by simply installing Xcode directly over osx-gcc-installer. Xcode sees it as an upgradable Xcode install.

Comment: Thanks - bummer with the Carbon headers though :-(