# Unable to install heroku gem on ruby 1.8.6

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I’m facing trouble trying to install the latest version of heroku gem (gives me an “abort trap” message). Currently it’s 2.17.0.

I’ve been able to install 2.3.6, and nothing greater (from 2.4 up I receive the “abort trap” message).

I’m using OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: I guess that you know you need 1.8.6 - 1.8.7 is much more popular than 1.8.6. If you are starting a new project, then usually you would use Ruby 1.9.2.  Ruby changed quite a bit going to 1.9.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Indeed, I really need 1.8.6, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM, the abort trap message is due wrong compiler being used to compile your Ruby installation. Take a look at [Why can't I install Rails on Lion using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170813/why-cant-i-install-rails-on-lion-using-rvm) to find your answer

Comment: Thanks, but I’m under Snow Leopard and gcc version 4.2.1. Do you know how to find the ruby version a gem depends on?