# Why am I having trouble compiling Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM on Mac OS Lion?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

I am having trouble installing Ruby 1.9.2 with rvm on Mac OS Lion.

It gets stuck in the compilation stage; I don't see any errors or output, but it will be stuck at the compilation message for hours upon hours. The miniruby process is still running and using quite a bit of CPU, but it just never finishes.

The only thing I can find in the logs is this message in the `make.log`:

```
<internal:prelude>:1: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas how I can get this to compile?

Answer (score 3):

What version of xcode are you using?

`rvm requirements` has this little tidbit:

```
** Lion Users: Xcode Version 4.2.x for OS X Lion works only for ruby 1.9.3-p0 (or higher).
               It currently fails to build several other rubies and gems, as well as several Homebrew and
               Macports packages. Xcode Version 4.1 (4B110) works.
```

Xcode v4.1 is at: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg

It's also important to make sure your RVM is current. Run `rvm get head` to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to Lion trying to use llvm to compile instead of gcc.  Try running the command like this `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.2` to use gcc.

Based on the information in this other answer: [Why can't I install Rails on Lion using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170813/why-cant-i-install-rails-on-lion-using-rvm)

Answer (score 0):

First read the installation notes of rvm, Follow the link which helped me [RVM on Mac](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/01/ruby-1-9-2-install-errors-with-mac-os-x-lion-and-rvm/)